# Drawing Pi Model in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Does anybody know how to draw the Pi Model [image: Pi Model]

in latex ?

I was thinking about using the tikz package but as I am new to latex I do not really know where to begin.

Comment: TikZ would certainly be the place to start. It has a great manual with tutorials. Also there are plenty of questions on the site you can look at. Try searching for "flow diagram". This should get you started.

Comment: You might be better off searching for 'block diagram' or something rather than 'graph'. Doesn't look much like a graph.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239462/drawing-a-block-diagram-with-tikz, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236704/how-to-draw-this-simple-box-diagram-with-tikz etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices, I will try them asap, they look just like what I need.